# The correct condition for OLS estimates to be unbiased?

Tags: regression, econometrics, assumptions, unbiased-estimator

For the ordinary least square (OLS) estimates of regression ($\vec{y} =\mathbf{X} \cdot \vec{\beta} + \vec{\epsilon}$) to be unbiased (without considering the efficiency), which one of the three conditions is required (sufficient):

$$\mathbb{E}(\vec{\epsilon}) = \vec{0}  \tag{Assumption 1}$$

$$\mathbb{E}(\vec{\epsilon} | \mathbf{X}) = \vec{0}  \tag{Assumption 2}$$

$$\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{X}^T \cdot \vec{\epsilon}) = \vec{0}  \tag{Assumption 3}$$

I came to the first one when deriving by myself:

The expectation of $\hat{\vec{\beta}}$ is:

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(\hat{\vec{\beta}}) & = \mathbb{E}[\vec{\beta} + (\mathbf{X}^T \cdot \mathbf{X})^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{X}^T \cdot\vec{\epsilon}] \\
& = \mathbb{E}(\vec{\beta}) + \mathbb{E}[(\mathbf{X}^T \cdot \mathbf{X})^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{X}^T \cdot\vec{\epsilon}] \\
& as\ \vec{\beta} \ is \ constant\ and\ \mathbf{X}\ is\ also\ constant\\
& = \vec{\beta} + (\mathbf{X}^T \cdot \mathbf{X})^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{X}^T \cdot \mathbb{E}(\vec{\epsilon}) \\
\end{align*} 
$$

But some materials in econometrics stated the Assumption 2 or Assumption 3.
I am confused as $\mathbf{X}$ is considered observed or fixed in OLS, conditioned expectation in Assumption 2 doesn't seem to make sense. And Assumption 3 should easily be simplified to Assumption 1 given $\mathbf{X}$ fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you regard $X$ as fixed then assumptions 1 and 2 are the same. Since $X$ often **isn't** fixed, just conditioned on, it's helpful to have the assumption in a form that doesn't rely on $X$ being fixed. That's the point of assumption 2. Both assumptions 1 and 2 are saying that $E[Y|X=x]$ is truly is $x\beta$.

Assumption 3 is importantly weaker. Assumptions 1 and 2 require **each** residual individually to have zero mean; assumption 3 only gives conditions on **sums** of residuals.

For example, suppose $E[Y|X=x]$ is actually a curve, so that $E[Y|X=x]\neq x\beta$.  There will still be a best-fitting true line, a value of $\beta$ that makes $E[X^Te]=0$, but we will not have $E[e_i|X_i=x]=0$ for any individual point. In this case it is still true that $\hat\beta$ is unbiased for the slope of the true best-fitting line, but that line is not $E[Y|X=x]$.

Comment: Thx! This makes so much sense.
But if we assume $\mathbf{X}$ to be random too:

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(\hat{\vec{\beta}}) = \vec{\beta} + \mathbb{E}_{X}[(\mathbf{X}^T \cdot \mathbf{X})^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{X}^T \cdot\mathbb{E}_{\vec{\epsilon}|X}(\vec{\epsilon}|\mathbf{X})]
\end{align*} 
$$

When $\mathbb{E}_{\vec{\epsilon}|X}(\vec{\epsilon}|\mathbf{X}) = 0$, it is indeed unbiased (sufficient). 

**But this isn't a necessary condition (non-zero inner expectations can cancel out in the outer one)**, right?

Comment: No, neither assumption 1 nor assumption 2 is necessary: assumption 3 is weaker, and is necessary.

Comment: Thanks a gain Thomas! I don't quite get how to derive assumption 3 when $\mathbf{X}$ is random. As $(\mathbf{X}^T \cdot \mathbf{X})^{-1}$ in $\mathbb{E}[(\mathbf{X}^T \cdot \mathbf{X})^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{X}^T \cdot\vec{\epsilon}]$ is also random, it seems we cannot take it out directly. How can we prove that $\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{X}^T \cdot \vec{\epsilon}) = \vec{0}$ will satisfy the unbiasness?

Comment: Condition on $X$.  It's unbiased for every fixed $X$ and therefore it's unbiased for random $X$.